# Can my friend and I spend the summer in Canada (6 weeks) at 16 years old without an adult?

Tags: uk, canada, minors

My friend’s parents have a house in Canada, I was wondering can we go there from the UK and stay for 6 weeks without an adult?

Comment: Your sixteen year old friend owns a house? That sounds rather suspicious.

Comment: @Amy Go there from where? How do you plan to travel there?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Probably just loose phrasing for "my friend's parents have a house".

Comment: From the uk, and yes obviously it’s her parents

Comment: "Six weeks", "summer" and "Canada" does not make sense in a sentence. Don't you know that summer in Canada is basically the last week in July?

Comment: @winny Perhaps you've never been to the Lower Mainland, it's summer there for a least a few months

Answer (score 27):

Yes, this is possible. In addition to a valid passport and an Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA), or visa (if you are not UK citizens/visa-free nationals http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp), from https://www.iatatravelcentre.com all children irrespective of nationality traveling alone are strongly advised to hold a consent letter signed by a legal guardian or parent with legal custody, containing:

- authorization to travel (with another person, when applicable) and to be outside the country;
- destination in Canada, also indicating length of stay;
- the signor's address and telephone details.

The Government of Canada provides a [sample](https://travel.gc.ca/travelling/children/consent-letter).

Airlines typically allow 16 year olds and over to travel unaccompanied but to be on the safe side you should check what the airline’s policy is before booking. You should also make sure you have proof of sufficient funds for the trip to show to Immigration Officers on arrival, and adequate travel insurance.

Comment: Note that while the flight is probably fine, transportation locally might be a challenge (e.g., no rental cars).

Comment: @chrylis In the UK we can't drive at 16 anyway, depends where in CAN they go, places like Vancouver have so much public transportation they will be fine. (But since the UK has buses and trains in every town they might expect this to be the same there)

Comment: Hitch-hiking is a great way to get around when you have time but not money.  Canada is not as nervous about this as the USA (case in point: US NPS prohibits hitch-hiking (probably for "safety" reasons), Parks Canada recommends it as an environmentally friendly way to get around)

Comment: @gerrit Hitch-hiking is no longer a common way to get around in the UK, parents of 16 year olds who live in the UK could be very uncomfortable with the idea

Comment: @Traveller Those parents who have let UK media scare them into seeing a pædophile behind every tree in the country may also be the helicopter parents who will not allow teenagers to spend six weeks abroad unsupervised.

Comment: @gerrit regardless of the motivation, hitch hiking in the UK is virtually non-existent. The only "hitch hikers" I see these days are professional vehicle delivery drivers looking for a free return trip (to boost their income by claiming the cost of the return fare and keeping it themselves) with similar professionals, and carrying their set of temporary vehicle licence plates as proof of their job status.

Comment: @alephzero Agreed - I guess the point here is that 16 year old travellers from the UK may have little or no understanding or awareness of how to hitch hike, whether that’s from a purely practical point of view (where can you do it, how do you do it, is it legal on all types of roads etc) or from a personal safety point of view

Comment: One issue might be health insurance and who can approve treatment if you're a minor.

Comment: @gerrit I'm not sure about the success rate of hitchhiking anymore.  I see less and less hitchhikers as time goes on in Canada.  Could be highly location dependent I guess.

Comment: As an aside, I think most of the airlines flying between the UK and Canada allow children to travel unaccompanied from the age of 8. I was 11 when I did this trip. It was a long time ago, but I was treated like royalty. It was a blast.

Comment: @alephzero I've seen hitch-hikers in the Lake District, and the only circumstances under which I've myself hitch-hiked by thumb is to get from a remote area to the nearest public transport after a hike (I've gotten rides from strangers in other circumstances, only after talking before they started driving). I wouldn't personally try to get across Canada hitch-hiking; long-distance buses are cheap enough and probably sufficiently adventurous for a couple of English youths. But if you find yourself ending a hike at a trailhead, seeking a spare spot in a car with other hikers is not too scary.

Comment: Do Uber and Lyft not work in Canada? Or traditional taxi services? This whole comment thread about hitchhiking seems off-topic at best.

Comment: @L.S.Cooper Ridesharing services are non-existent in Canada outside major cities. Searching a few vacation destinations, there is no Uber service in Victoria, Whistler, Kelowna, Regina, Sault St. Marie, Halifax, PEI... In these low-density areas, taxis are going to take hours to show up and charge you a small fortune.

Comment: @user71659 I stand corrected, then! Still, I would never advise a 16-year-old girl to go hitchhiking as her primary form of transportation, and there's probably other, better ways to navigate.